# Get filename from url google sheet

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem.
How to get the filename from the url?
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM7b1.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add images rather as images than as links. This time I've done this for you - please see [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting. You probably have to add more details to your question, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Tried anything? Done any research *at all*? Why is this tagged both Excel and Google spreadsheet? Are your links in Excel, and you're trying to get the name of files on Google Drive? This is why providing specific details in your question helps everyone - your question is well received, and people trying to answer have no ambiguities to resolve (or ignore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't normally do this since you haven't shown us what you've tried, but I'm feeling generous.

This function should work for you. (Note that you'll need to grant permissions for it to run.)

```
function getFileNames() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Get_File_Name");
  var links = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var filenames = []; 
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var url = links[i][0];
    if (url != "") {
      var filename = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(links[i][0]).getName();
      filenames.push([filename]);
    }
  }
  var startRow = 2; // print in row 2 since row 1 is the header row
  var fileNameColumn = 2; // Column B = column 2
  var destination = sheet.getRange(startRow, fileNameColumn, filenames.length, filenames[0].length);
  destination.setValues(filenames);
}
```

Comment: This assumes that all links will be spreadsheet documents btw. Given that the name is wanted, I would use `DriveApp` instead for maximum compatibility.

Comment: Thanks, that's a very fair point @tehhowch. Given the image, it looks like they're all spreadsheets, but I'll leave it to the poster to modify the code if needed.

Comment: Your function name is generic :) One would certainly hope anyone who copies code to achieve a purpose actually reads and comprehends said code, but there are plenty who ask questions about "Service Unavailable: Docs / Sheets" errors when their own code blindly opens a file without checking for the appropriate mimetype.

Comment: I get error message "Document 1TEvq1qIAAVAeXfiRTj3GE-5SOA3n5ojWAijxwkJVssQ is missing (perhaps it was deleted?)"

Comment: @Diego can you edit the question to make your answer useful? I struggle to understand what OP is asking. You seem to have understood, so please edit the question so that others can understand it and your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
function getFileNames() {
  var driveApp = DriveApp;
  // SET THE SHEET HERE
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //SET THE URL LINK COLUMN HERE : From row 2 since row 1 is the header row till last row
  var links = sheet.getRange("P2:P").getValues();

  var filenames = []; 

  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var fileId = getIdFromUrl(links[i][0]);
    if (fileId != "" && fileId != null) {
      var getfile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
      var filename = getfile.getName();
      Logger.log(filename);
      filenames.push([filename]);
    } else {
      filenames.push([""]); 
    }
  }

  // SET STARTING ROW TO PRINT: From row 2 since row 1 is the header row
  var startRow = 2; 
  // SET WHICH COLUMN TO PRINT : Column A = column 1 / Column B = column 2
  // MAKE SURE THE SHEET LAST COLUMN HEADER IS FILLED + 1 (next column)
  var fileNameColumn = sheet.getLastColumn() + 1;  
  var destination = sheet.getRange(startRow, fileNameColumn, filenames.length, filenames[0].length);
  destination.setValues(filenames);
}

function getIdFromUrl(url) { return url.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create a custom function in spreadsheets like this.

```
function getSSName(name) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  return ss.getName();
}
```

Comment: The argument should be `url` instead of `name`

Comment: The script is not running sir.
 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UfZuhRRpAOBe8bKKTfELlPmcnV9FjMhbxDVxF3BAvY4/edit#gid=196705363

Comment: You can't use a custom function that opens _other_ spreadsheets. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services